# innerHTML removing closing slash from image tag

Tags: javascript, image, xhtml, innerhtml

This is very odd. Here is a quick test function:

```
function test_function(){
    code = '<img src="http://www.myimage.com/img.jpg" alt="image" />';
    alert(code);
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = code;
    alert(document.getElementById('test').innerHTML);
}
```

Running the code above will show `/>` in the first alert, but the second alert doesn't, it shows just `>`. So it looks like applying to `.innerHTML` strips out the forward slash. Any ideas how to stop this from happening? I need the forward slash for validation.

Comment: what doctype do you use?

Comment: With which browsers are you experiencing this?

Comment: If the browser removes the forward slash, it is likely to be not required in that doctype.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Comment: But do you serve your web page as `application/xhtml+xml`?

Comment: I suppose you mean this: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"   content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />

Comment: No, I meant the [HTTP header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_header).

Comment: right, its coming through as text/html

Comment: In which case browsers are parsing your page as HTML anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second alert just shows you what the browser uses as its internal representation of your image element. You don't need the slash for validation, as validation always is about your page's source, validators don't execute JavaScript that dynamically adds elements to the DOM.

In fact, most browsers handle XHTML internally just the same as HTML, not as an XML-representation of your document. Only when you send your XHTML document with MIME-type `application/xhtml+xml`, *some* browsers will render your page using the XML parser.

Also see Ian Hickson's [article](http://hixie.ch/advocacy/xhtml).

Comment: Thats all well and good, unless you are using things like innerHTML to save page source into an ajax page editor.

Comment: Right, so if I use that mime, it will work in some browser. I need something sure fire and can't find anything online apart form using that mime.

Comment: @David – Can't you switch to HTML 5 here? It is much more forgiving when you don't use [self-closing tags](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#elements-0).

Comment: To work around this, parse the string and add it manually: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8764669/2065702