# jQuery/Javascript pulling html/innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div id="test">
    <img align="right" src="images/home-faqs.jpg" alt="FAQS" width="428" />
</div>
```

So I pull #test innerHTML but the result is

```
<img align="right" src="images/home-faqs.jpg" alt="FAQS" width="428">
```

it removes the closing slashes, how do I get javascript not to do that?

Comment: This has come up before, consult this question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244434/innerhtml-removing-closing-slash-from-image-tag  It has some insight, anyhow.

Comment: Read the above comment for sure.

Answer (score 1):

That is mostly an artifact of the browser and the library.  You won't be able to stop that if you are using an an HTML doctype, but it isn't important.  The XML-style closing slash is actually not part of the HTML standard.  When you're in an XML doctype, javascript will keep the slashes.

Validation only applies to the page as it loads before javascript changes the DOM, so no worries on that front, either.

Comment: well it is a part of XHTML standard, but it still doesn't work properly with XHTML Doctypes.

Comment: But again, for the strict purpose of validating a document, changes rendered after-the-fact are generally excluded.  Javascript always creates valid DOM nodes by virtue of the fact it is directly interacting with DOM to create and manipulate them.  As long as you aren't creating them using strings (i.e. `ele.innerHTML = '<span This is not valid</p>';`), when javascript creates a node, it is valid for the document it created it within.